# API Signature Generation

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, oauth, cryptography

I'm working on a Node.js app... Trying to request data from the JWPlatform API and having a hard time creating the auth signature. Maybe I'm going about this completely wrong, but I have reached out to the JWPlatform dev team and they said they are not familiar enough with Node or JS to point out what I'm doing wrong... They offer both a PHP API Kit and a Python API Kit, which I have looked through, but still don't see where my misstep is.

To make things a little more simple here, I've hardcoded the variables and am simply trying to output an identical SHA-1 Hex Digest as found in their [documented example](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/botr/system-api/authentication.html) which is included at the bottom of this post.

*Documented Example*: `fbdee51a45980f9876834dc5ee1ec5e93f67cb89`

*Current Output*: `f067ff121b5a4388fecc00f01dabeddd02d707f4`

Hokay, So. I think that's enough info.

### Here's my code

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

test = {
  apiFormat: 'xml',
  apiKey: 'XOqEAfxj',
  apiNonce: 80684843,
  apiTimestamp: 1237387851,
  apiText: ('démo').toString("utf8"),
  apiSecret: 'uA96CFtJa138E2T5GhKfngml'
}

// Concatinate string
concat = "api_format=" + test.apiFormat +
  "&api_key=" + test.apiKey +
  "&api_nonce=" + test.apiNonce +
  "&api_timestamp=" + test.apiTimestamp +
  "&text=" + encodeURI(test.apiText);

// Create Hash
testSignature = crypto.createHmac("sha1", concat+
  test.apiSecret).digest("hex");

console.log(testSignature);
// Outputs:   'f067ff121b5a4388fecc00f01dabeddd02d707f4'
// Expecting: 'fbdee51a45980f9876834dc5ee1ec5e93f67cb89'
```

### Their [documentation](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/botr/system-api/authentication.html):

#### 1: All text parameters converted to UTF-8 encoding.

```
text: démo
api_format: xml
api_key: XOqEAfxj
api_nonce: 80684843
api_timestamp: 1237387851
```

#### 2: All text parameters URL-encoded (see OAuth Core 1.0 Section 5.1).

```
text: d%C3%A9mo
api_format: xml
api_key: XOqEAfxj
api_nonce: 80684843
api_timestamp: 1237387851
```

#### 3: Parameters are sorted based on their encoded names (see OAuth Core 1.0 Section 9.1.1). Sort order is lexicographical byte value ordering.

```
api_format: xml
api_key: XOqEAfxj
api_nonce: 80684843
api_timestamp: 1237387851
text: d%C3%A9mo
```

#### 4: Parameters are concatenated together into a single string. Each parameter’s name is separated from the corresponding value by an ‘=’ character (even if the value is empty), and each name-value pair is separated by an ‘&’ character (see OAuth Core 1.0 Section 9.1.1).

```
api_format=xml&api_key=XOqEAfxj&api_nonce=80684843&api_timestamp=1237387851&text=d%C3%A9mo
```

#### 5: The secret is added and SHA-1 digest is calculated. Secret is added to the end of the SBS:

```
api_format=xml&api_key=XOqEAfxj&api_nonce=80684843&api_timestamp=1237387851&text=d%C3%A9mouA96CFtJa138E2T5GhKfngml
```

#### 6: The calculated SHA-1 HEX digest for the above string will be:

```
fbdee51a45980f9876834dc5ee1ec5e93f67cb89
```

#### An authenticated API call will look like this:

```
http://api.jwplatform.com/v1/videos/list?text=d%C3%A9mo&api_nonce=80684843&api_timestamp=1237387851&api_format=xml&api_signature=fbdee51a45980f9876834dc5ee1ec5e93f67cb89&api_key=XOqEAfxj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're actually okay up to the hashing stage. You're trying to use the HMAC functions, but I think they're just using a hash. Try this:

```
testSignature = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(concat + test.apiSecret).digest('hex');
```

This should get you the hex string `fbdee51a45980f9876834dc5ee1ec5e93f67cb89`.